# How to use Log4OM with multiple users?

Tags: software, logging

My household has multiple licensed amateur radio operators that share the equipment (ham radio, computer, etc).  We would like to use Log4OM to log our QSQs and to use the program to submit them to LOTW, eLog, QRZ, etc.  However, each of us has their own corresponding accounts and we would like to keep our logs separate.

Can this be achieved via different Log4OM profiles?  If so is there an easy way to specify what profile to use at start up (i.e. via the command line/shortcut)?

We are using the same Windows user account and do not want to utilize different Windows user accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a specific profile is quite straight forward and documented in this setting screen:

[image]

Source: http://forum.log4om.com/viewtopic.php?t=2641#p15009

To configure TQSL to sign with the correct LOTW key, specify a station location for each key:

[image]

And choose the appropriate location in the LOTW Settings of Log4OM:

[image]